# How to change the name from Ethereum on a private blockchain

Tags: ether

So i followed some tutorials to make my own private version of ethereum, thats all good and working fine, but how can I change the name "Ethereum" "ETH" "ether" to basically have the name of my coin? what parts need changing?

A search and replace was not a good result :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this with geth?